# How to periodically save a web page to server using PHP?

Tags: php

How to automatically and periodically save from this [page](http://example.com/page.html) to my web server with **PHP**?

http://example.com/page.html

**You can make a web page scraper script in PHP, then schedule it to run using cron jobs.**

```
<?php
// Call this file 'scraper.php'
$local_file = "local.html"; // local destination
$remote_file = "http://example.com/page.html"; // source
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);?>
```

You can make a web page scraper script in PHP, then schedule it to run using cron jobs.

**To automatically run this script every day, make a cron job something like this**

```
* 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /root/document/path/scraper.php
```

*where scraper.php is the name of the code block above, /usr/bin/php is the server path to the PHP interpreter, and * 0 * * * are timing parameters that make the script run once per day. *

**If you want to save the webpage to your server as a local file you could do it like this:**

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/page.html");file_put_contents("/path/to/local.html", $html);
```

below code not working pleas fix it

```
if (!file_exists('/local_mis.php')) {
mkdir('/causelist/madras/causelist/misc/', 0777, true);}
```

Comment: what you try to ask?

Comment: I am try to save html page is save my local server load automatic

Comment: Why did you add "jquery script"?

Comment: sorry i am removed jquery script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a web page scraper script in PHP, then schedule it to run using [cron jobs](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml).

```
<?php
    // Call this file 'scraper.php'
    $local_file = "local.html"; // local destination
    $remote_file = "http://example.com/page.html"; // source

    $ch = curl_init();
    $fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($remote_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

To automatically run this script every day, make a [cron job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) something like this

```
* 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /root/document/path/scraper.php
```

where `scraper.php` is the name of the code block above, `/usr/bin/php` is the server path to the PHP interpreter, and `* 0 * * *` are timing parameters that make the script run once per day.

All servers are different, and I don't know what server you are running, but here are instructions for setting cron jobs in Ubunutu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: $local_file = "local.html"; how to made own location folder

Comment: I need you to give a clear example of what "automatic" means in this case. Please give an example of where you want the data from that web page to be saved on your local server

Comment: above script automatic Running on date and time schedule

Comment: Do you know about cron jobs? That's what you are into now. Completely outside of PHP. If you don't know, then I can provide some links. Cron jobs are the best way for automatic script execution on a schedule.

Comment: I've added information on how to schedule this script

Comment: i am not know cron jobs pleas provide script

Comment: That is the 'script'. That's it. That's all :) I don't know your server, but all of them let you schedule cron jobs. For example, on ubuntu, here are instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the webpage to your server as a local file you could do it like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/page.html");
file_put_contents("/path/to/local.html", $html);
```

Comment: show this error: Warning: file_put_contents(http://localhost/CL/local.html): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in F:\LAWTURN\Ofline\wamp\www\CL\local.php on line 3

Comment: how to server script automatic load

Comment: pleas fix it   if (!file_exists('/local_mis.php')) {
mkdir('/causelist/madras/causelist/misc/', 0777, true);}